# Why is the text on asp.net controls is not changed when changing uiCulture

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, controls, globalization

I have user control on aspx page.
The uc has dropdownlist control for selecting one of three languages: Hebrew (default), English or Russian.
I have three resx pages contain the translation of each language.
when the user selects a language, I change the uiCulture of the parent page to selected option:

```
this.Page.UICulture = language;
```

It works.
but... not completely.
I have div defined as follow:

```
<div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-4"><%= Resources.MyResource.CurrencyText %></div>
```

and its content changed as expected.
but I have also dropdownlist defined:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Height="16px">
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<%$ Resources:MyResource,shekelOpt %>"></asp:listitem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2"  Text="<%$ Resources:MyResource,dollarOpt %>"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and it does not changes at all.
I tried to workaround and ti write in $(document).ready function something like:

```
$("#<%= ddlCurrency.ClientID %> option:nth-child(1)").text("<%= Resources.MyResource.shekelOpt %>");
$("#<%= ddlCurrency.ClientID %> option:nth-child(2)").text("<%= Resources.MyResource.dollarOpt %>");
```

it works, but I don't like this solution, It is ugly and not enough built.

can someone help and tell me how to cause the text on asp:dropdownlist (and also on asp:button) to be changed?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use label and define the text in the resx to change.

Comment: how can i define label inside dropdownlist?

Comment: let me search, I didn't faced this issue in past. Will let you know if I get some solution

Comment: Did you have shekelOpt and dollarOpt in all 3 resx page?

Comment: of course!!! when I change it in jQuery code as I showed it works, but I can't change all the controls manually by code.

Comment: Based upon your code it looks like you are trying to access global resource keys from web.config. If you want to access local resources, you can do that by referring the answer which I posted.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly I have to do. can you please explain me? many thanks.

Comment: I tried your edition. not working.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it and it worked. What does it mean? how can I make it working with user's selection?

Comment: well, that's what I did. It worked (By the way, my code behind is written in c#).

Comment: soryy...... just now I saw your full edition (with images) because my browser did not show them. I did exactly what you told and it simply worked!!! no words!!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this in ResourceClearing.aspx.vb for testing ru-RU culture. Do not set the culture outside of InitializeCulture:**

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
                    base.InitializeCulture();
                }
```

**Add this in ResourceClearing.aspx Page**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Height="16px">
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<%$ Resources:shekelOpt %>"></asp:listitem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2"  Text="<%$ Resources:dollarOpt %>"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If that doesn't work add this markup in ResourceClearing.aspx Page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Height="16px" meta:resourcekey="ddlCurrencyResource1" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Shekal" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2"  Text="Dollar" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

And add the following entries in all 3 resource files with their values:

[image]

Comment: now I get error  'The resource object with key 'shekelOpt' not found'. I know it does exist.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of 3 .resx pages which have the entries?

Comment: you mean the content of each one of them?

Comment: Yes, anything...From your code it looks like you are trying to access global resource, but you need to define entries in all 3 resx files

Comment: Edit your question and then ctrl+G

Comment: Editing my answer in sometime...Please review if you have completed all the steps.

Comment: of course! sorry about the delay. accidently I commented my question in place of ypur answer. you are genius!!! now it works perfectly. I have no words to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your codebehind override both properties for culture and UIculture

```
protected override void InitializeCulture (){
  UICulture = selectedLanguage;
        Culture = selectedLanguage;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
        base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed. maybe something in web.config?

Comment: Where have to kept your resources in App_GlobalResources or App_LocalResources  Folder. you need to have your resources in App_GlobalResources Folder

Comment: I have them in this folder. The strange point is (at least for me) that labels and divs do change, and only Text attributes of controls remain unchanged.

Comment: Can you try it using this must work `Text='<%# GetGlobalResourceObject([ResourceClassName],[ResourceKey]) %>'`

Comment: when I write it on my button  Text='<%# GetGlobalResourceObject("resources.MyResource","submitText") %>' I get empty text

Comment: when I write Text='<%# "123" %>'  I also get empty string! and in debug mode I can see that the expression GetGlobalResourceObject("resources.MyResource","submitText") returns the right value! what can be the problem?

Comment: ok if you are getting correct value in debug you need to do a small change replace # with = `Text='<%= GetGlobalResourceObject([ResourceClassName],[ResourceKey]) %>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66397/discussion-between-ariela-and-akshayrandive).